# applescript (automator) how can I access properties of the selected image in keynote?

Tags: image, applescript, automator, keynote

```
tell application "Keynote"
    activate
    tell the front document
        tell the current slide
            set ImageItem to **image 1**
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

When I use such a script, I can access images by their index. However, if I want the selected image in keynote, what should I do?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because Keynote doesn't have a `selection` property

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Eventually, I find another way to realize what I need.